# Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/libexec/java_home/bin/keytool" (-1)

Tags: bash, android-studio, firebase, keytool, sha

Hi I want to generate SHA1 fingerprint to use firebase in my project. I tried to use keytool to generate SHA1 fingerprint using this command

keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore

But it is giving me following error
Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/libexec/java_home/bin/keytool" (-1)

Here I am telling you where is my jdk located and also my bash profile entries.

Jdk is not located in user/Library/Java but I opened it from here
file:///Applications/Android%20Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool

Here are my bash-profile entries:

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home

export JAVA7_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7

Kindly guide me in detail how can i set my jdk outside AndroidStudio contents also how to edit bash-profile.

Would be highly thankful to you.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be easier for you to skip keytool and instead run this Gradle target to get the SHA-1 for your app:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

It will dump the SHA-1 of each of the variants of your app.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But Could you please tell me how can i setup jdk for AndroidStudio and make entries in bash-profile. I need detail answer please.

Answer (score 0):

no wonder this isn't working, a lot has changed since 2013 !